# if $f''$ is continuous then $f''(x_0)=0$ where $x_0$ is an inflection point

Tags: calculus

I came across the following statement and I am trying to get some intuition why is it right.

"if $f''$ is continuous then $f''(x_0)=0$ where $x_0$ is an inflection point, take a note: the opposite is not true: $f''(x_0)=0\not{\rightarrow} x_0$ an inflection point

Comment: Suppose that $f=x^4$, at $x=0$, the second derivative is zero but 0 is not an inflection point.

Comment: @Simo  Which is an example of why, as gbox stated, the opposite is not true.